# Dynamic table name in postgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgreSQL. I want to select data from a table. Such table name contains the current year. such as abc2013. I have tried

```
select * from concat('abc',date_part('year',current_date)) 

select  *from from  concat('abc', extract (year from current_date))
```

So how to fetch data from such table dynamically?

Comment: Why don't you use table inheritance and partitioning instead?

Comment: I am having different tables for each year and I want to fetch data as per user selected year.

Comment: That's exactly what table inheritance and partitioning is for: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Answer (score 3):

Please don't do this - look hard at alternatives first, starting with [partitioning and constraint exclusion](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html).

If you must use dynamic table names, do it at application level during query generation.

If all else fails you can use a PL/PgSQL procedure like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE pleasedont(int year) RETURNS TABLE basetable AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM %I', 'basetable_'||year);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This will only work if you have a base table that has the same structure as the sub-tables. It's also really painful to work with when you start adding qualifiers (where clause constraints, etc), and it prevents any kind of plan caching or effective prepared statement use.