# How do I retrieve all tuples from similar tables in a postgresql database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a postgresql database with a nice property. All tables within this database have the same schema. They were created using this model query.

```
CREATE TABLE tableX (s varchar(100), p varchar(100), o varchar(100))
```

Now I'm interested on retrieving all data from these tables in one shot. I can get all their names using the following query :

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'
```

but I struggle to return the contain of all tables ( whose name is in result of the above query). I've try the following query

```
SELECT tab.s, tab.p, tab.o  
FROM (SELECT table_name 
      FROM information_schema.tables 
      WHERE table_schema='public') AS tab
```

but it's not working. And I get the following error message from pgadm3

```
ERROR:  column tab.s does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT tab.s, tab.p, tab.o
           ^
********** Erreur **********

ERROR: column tab.s does not exist
État SQL :42703
Caractère : 151
```

Any idea how to deal with this ?

Comment: Not sure whether your can do it with direct sql, but I'm sure it will be possile to do it via pl/SQL

Comment: You need to build a dynamic select statement for each table, and then an enormous `union all` of all of them, and run them as a dynamic sql statement in a plpgsql function or do statement.

Comment: As it is said above: you can generate a query that contain unions of all those table using pl/sql.

Comment: @Denis can you please provide a sample of such a code ?

Comment: Having "numbered" tables with the same layout sounds like a strange design. You should look into partitioning/table inheritance

Comment: Build the SQL string, and then http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN OR alter all tables so they inherit the same parent, as suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name. see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic table name in postgreSQL 9.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469687/dynamic-table-name-in-postgresql-9-3)